# Accidentally recitate more

Tags: salat, mistake

Assalamu'alaiykum

Is somebody salat valid if someone recite more than needed accidentally?

For example, if someone recite a surah after Al-Fatihah in third rakaah of Isya, even just the basmallah part then he cut it

Or, if someone accindentally recite Shalawat in first tasyahud (For the people who think the tahiyat is enough at frist tasyahud), even if not completed then he cut it

Oh, and is there any difference whether when he accidentally do it when salat in congregation and alone?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

> Is somebody salat valid if someone recite more than needed accidentally?

Yes it is. You might have done something which is frowned upon according some scholars, but it doesn't count as a mistake or something that invalidates the prayer.

Comment: Do i have to do sujood as-sahw if that happens?

Comment: @Bejo no not AFAIK.